# Firestore function Gen 2 with failurePolicy

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

For the life of me, I cant find any info or doc on getting failurePolicy working with Firestore function Gen 2 on firestore trigger (onDocumentCreated). Would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.

Thank you!~

I have tried with .runwith like gen 1 but its not working